# Draftail blockquote with it's own css class added, is this possible?

Tags: rich-text-editor, wagtail

I managed to add a blockquote with a css class button to the draftail (code below) and it works ok. The only issue so far is if I try and a link to a word using the standard link button in the editor within that blockquote text, I get a JS error (also below)

I've tried to adapt the stock example from the docs, but I'm guessing I've messed up something.

The code in wagtail_hooks.py

```
def poquote_entity_decorator(props):
    """
    Draft.js ContentState to database HTML.
    Converts the poquote entities into a blockquote with class tag.
    """
    return DOM.create_element('blockquote', {
        'class': 'pullout',
    }, props['children'])


class PoQuoteEntityElementHandler(InlineEntityElementHandler):
"""
Database HTML to Draft.js ContentState.
Converts the blockquote tag into a PoQuote entity, with the right 
data.
"""
mutability = 'IMMUTABLE'

def get_attribute_data(self, attrs):
    return {
        'poquote': attrs['class'],
    }

@hooks.register('insert_editor_js')
def draftail_editor_js():
js_files = [
    'wagtailadmin/js/draftail.js',
    'js/draftail.js',
]
js_includes = format_html_join('\n', '<script src="{0}{1}"> 
</script>',
    ((settings.STATIC_URL, filename) for filename in js_files)
)
return js_includes

@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_poquote_feature(features):
    features.default_features.append('poquote')
    """
    Registering the `poquote` feature, which uses the `POQUOTE` 
    Draft.js entity type,
    and is stored as HTML with a `<blockquote class='pullout'>` tag.
    """
    feature_name = 'poquote'
    type_ = 'POQUOTE'

    control = {
        'type': type_,
        'icon': 'icon icon-form',
        'description': 'Pull Out Quote',
    }

    features.register_editor_plugin(
        'draftail', feature_name, 
    draftail_features.EntityFeature(control)
    )

features.register_converter_rule('contentstate', feature_name, {
    # Note here that the conversion is more complicated than for 
     blocks and inline styles.
    'from_database_format': {'blockquote[class]': 
    PoQuoteEntityElementHandler(type_)},
    'to_database_format': {'entity_decorators': {type_: 
    poquote_entity_decorator}},
})
```

and the JS

```
const React = window.React;
const Modifier = window.DraftJS.Modifier;
const EditorState = window.DraftJS.EditorState;

// Not a real React component – just creates the entities as soon as 
it is rendered.
class PoqSource extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { editorState, entityType, onComplete } = this.props;

        const content = editorState.getCurrentContent();
        const selection = editorState.getSelection();

        const anchorKey = selection.getAnchorKey();
        const currentBlock = content.getBlockForKey(anchorKey);

        const start = selection.getStartOffset();
        const end = selection.getEndOffset();
        const selectedText = currentBlock.getText().slice(start, 
end);

       // Uses the Draft.js API to create a new entity with the right 
data.
       const contentWithEntity = 
content.createEntity(entityType.type, 'IMMUTABLE', {
        poq: selectedText,
       });
       const entityKey = contentWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();


       // We also add some text for the entity to be activated on.
       const text = `${selectedText}`;

       const newContent = Modifier.replaceText(content, selection, 
text, null, entityKey);
       const nextState = EditorState.push(editorState, newContent, 
'insert-characters');

       onComplete(nextState);
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}

const Poq = (props) => {
    const { entityKey, contentState } = props;
    const data = contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getData();

    return React.createElement('blockquote',  {className: 'pullout'}, 
props.children);
};

window.draftail.registerPlugin({
   type: 'POQUOTE',
   source: PoqSource,
   decorator: Poq,
});
```

The error :

```
vendor.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
at h (VM7359 draftail.js:1)
at n.value (VM7359 draftail.js:1)
at commitLifeCycles (vendor.js:1)
at e (vendor.js:1)
at x (vendor.js:1)
at w (vendor.js:1)
at batchedUpdates (vendor.js:1)
at Z (vendor.js:1)
at It (vendor.js:1)
l @ vendor.js:1
vendor.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of 
undefined
at h (VM7359 draftail.js:1)
at n.value (VM7359 draftail.js:1)
at commitLifeCycles (vendor.js:1)
at e (vendor.js:1)
at x (vendor.js:1)
at w (vendor.js:1)
at batchedUpdates (vendor.js:1)
at Z (vendor.js:1)
at It (vendor.js:1)
vendor.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
at h (VM7359 draftail.js:1)
at n.value (VM7359 draftail.js:1)
at commitLifeCycles (vendor.js:1)
at e (vendor.js:1)
at x (vendor.js:1)
at w (vendor.js:1)
at batchedUpdates (vendor.js:1)
at Z (vendor.js:1)
at It (vendor.js:1)
l @ vendor.js:1
vendor.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of 
undefined
at h (VM7359 draftail.js:1)
at n.value (VM7359 draftail.js:1)
at commitLifeCycles (vendor.js:1)
at e (vendor.js:1)
at x (vendor.js:1)
at w (vendor.js:1)
at batchedUpdates (vendor.js:1)
at Z (vendor.js:1)
at It (vendor.js:1)
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is a block as `<blockquote class='pullout'>my text</blockquote>`, there is a simpler way to do it without writing JavaScript code.

First, start from the example in the [official documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/advanced_topics/customisation/extending_draftail.html#creating-new-blocks) about blocks, using blockquote:

```python
from wagtail.admin.rich_text.converters.html_to_contentstate import BlockElementHandler

@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_blockquote_feature(features):
    """
    Registering the `blockquote` feature, which uses the `blockquote` Draft.js block type,
    and is stored as HTML with a `<blockquote>` tag.
    """
    feature_name = 'blockquote'
    type_ = 'blockquote'
    tag = 'blockquote'

    control = {
        'type': type_,
        'label': '❝',
        'description': 'Blockquote',
        # Optionally, we can tell Draftail what element to use when displaying those blocks in the editor.
        'element': 'blockquote',
    }

    features.register_editor_plugin(
        'draftail', feature_name, draftail_features.BlockFeature(control)
    )

    features.register_converter_rule('contentstate', feature_name, {
        'from_database_format': {tag: BlockElementHandler(type_)},
        'to_database_format': {'block_map': {type_: tag}},
    })
```

You can write styles to display those blocks in the editor with the `Draftail-block--blockquote` class.

Then, you need to adapt the converter rules so this is stored as `<blockquote class='pullout'>my text</blockquote>` with the `pullout` class:

```python
features.register_converter_rule('contentstate', feature_name, {
    'from_database_format': {'blockquote[class]': BlockElementHandler(type_)},
    'to_database_format': {
        'block_map': {
            type_: {
                'element': tag,
                'props': {
                    'class': 'pullout',
                },
            },
        },
    },
})
```

Of course you can use the `poquote` type and-or feature name if you want to, no need to use `blockquote`.

Comment: Thanks though this doesn't work for me as I already have a normal blockquote button added using an example I found, in fact basically the same as the first bit of code you added. I guess this would work if I just wanted one blockquote button with a class on every blockquote but I'm trying to get one normal blockquote button, and another which is a blockquote with a specific class.

Comment: @joss this is the last part of my response – you can use another `type` and feature name for each of the blockquote-like features. As long as all the blocks have different `type` and feature identifiers, you can have as many as you want.

Comment: I did use different type and feature name, only the element was the same. It still didn't work, I'll have a look again and double check

Comment: Awesome! I have to add a css class to an existing element (h1 and h2). Is it safe to overwrite the registry ``features.converter_rules_by_converter['contentstate']['h2']``? Or should I rather reregister the rule by invoking ``register_converter_rule``? When I see the source both should be fine but wondering what you as a contributor would say to that.

Comment: @YannicHamann at first glance it sounds safer to re-register. `converter_rules_by_converter` is not a public API.